# What is wrong with this code? (Array of objects, null pointer exception.)

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have created an array of objects for abc class, but it gives a null pointer exception whenever i call the `accept()` code which gets the data from the user.

This is the code:

```java
   class abc{
    int rollno,i;
    String name;
    public void accept(){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter roll no: ");
        rollno=sc.nextInt();
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Roll no: "+rollno);
    }

    public static void main(String[] gs){
        int i;
        abc a[]=new abc[10];

        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            a[i].accept();    //This line gives null pointer exception
        }

        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            a[i].display();
        }   
}
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `a[i]` is `null`. It is not initialized by default. You are creating an array of reference type `abc` of 10 elements . All the elements in the array will be `null` references.You need to assign a concrete object of type `abc` to each of these references before invoking any method.

You need to instantiate objects before invoking any method on it :

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   a[i] = new abc(); // instantiate it
   a[i].accept();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you never initialize the elements in the array.

```
abc a[] = new abc[10];
```

creates a new array, but it does not instantiate the objects in the array.

You need to do

```
abc a[] = new abc[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = new abc();
    a[i].accept();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because the all elements of `abc a[]=new abc[10];` array will be initialized with null values. whenever you invoke any method on null reference, it will produces null pointer exception.you can void this null ponter exception by intializing the array element by adding `a[i] = new abc();`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated memory to your array positions, i.e before

```
a[i].accept();
```

you have to include

```
a[i] = new abc();
```

>> If you find my answer correct, do remember to mark it correct..